# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:5(Bucle)

Tags: java, array, while

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]estoy tratando de hacer un  ahorcado (juego) digitas una palabra, tu mismo ingreses las letras para completar la palabra, para eso hice un if que verifica si la letra de entrada digitada por ti pertence a la palabra previamente, si es asi se suma 1 al contador iniciando en 0, para que el programa acabe el contador tiene que ser del mismo valor de caracteres que tiene la palabra pero a la hora de que completas la palabra te pide la letra una vez mas y marca exepcion de tipo ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

```
char ahorcado[] = new char[palabra.length()-1];//Crea array con ==# de carac que la palabra

    int k = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    

    do{

        System.out.println("Digite la letra que cree que esta en la palabra");
        letra = entrada.next().charAt(0);
        lei = palabra.indexOf(letra);
        
        if (lei != -1 ){

            ahorcado[i] = letra;
            System.out.println(ahorcado[i]); //Linea para verificar que entro en el array
            System.out.println("Letra correcta");
            k++; //Cada que se acierta una letra suma 1
            
        }
        else{
            
            System.out.println("Letra incorrecta");
            
        }
        i++;
        
        
    }
    while(kintroducir la descripción de la imagen aquí<palabra.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

El error está aquí:

```
 char ahorcado[] = new char[palabra.length() -1 ];
```

Se está creando un arreglo con una longitud menor a la palabra. La forma correcta es así:

```
new char[palabra.length()];
```

Eso crea un arreglo con una longitud igual a la palabra. `length() - 1` se usa para obtener el último índice del arreglo debido a que los índices inician en 0.